# Script Error with a spfx webpart on german classic publishing page

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

After inserting the SPFX webpart in a classic publishing page we got a script error ")" missing.

This script loads the webpart and has a syntax error:

```
<script>(function cswp_WPQ2(global) {
    if (global.moduleLoaderPromise) {
      global.moduleLoaderPromise.then(function(application) {
        try {
          application.loadWebPart("g_123", "123", "<div data-sp-webpart=\"\" data-sp-webpartdataversion=1.0 data-sp-webpartdata=\"&#123;&quot;id&quot;&#58;&quot;55c82295-5067-40bc-b87b-bb9f2486c158&quot;,&quot;instanceId&quot;&#58;null,&quot;title&quot;&#58;&quot;Name&quot;,&quot;description&quot;&#58;&quot;Get and render activities&quot;,&quot;version&quot;&#58;&quot;0.0.1&quot;,&quot;properties&quot;&#58;&#123;&quot;activity_source_type&quot;&#58;&quot;user&quot;,&quot;activity_source&quot;&#58;&quot;0&quot;&#125;,&quot;htmlProperties&quot;&#58;null&#125;\"><div data-sp-componentid=\"\">123</div><div data-sp-htmlproperties=\"\"></div></div>", 2, 2, false, []);
          }
        catch (e) {
          if (application != null && application.logClientSideWebPartLoadError != null) {
            application.logClientSideWebPartLoadError("123", "Ein Webpart auf dieser Seite kann nicht geladen werden. Verwenden Sie die Schaltfläche "Zurück" im Browser, um es noch mal zu versuchen. Wenn das Problem weiterhin besteht, wenden Sie sich an den Administrator der Website, und teilen Sie ihm die Informationen unter "Technische Details" mit.");
            console.error(e);
          }
          else {
              console.error("Ein Webpart auf dieser Seite kann nicht geladen werden. Verwenden Sie die Schaltfläche "Zurück" im Browser, um es noch mal zu versuchen. Wenn das Problem weiterhin besteht, wenden Sie sich an den Administrator der Website, und teilen Sie ihm die Informationen unter "Technische Details" mit.");
              console.error(e);
          }
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      console.error("Der Webpart-Wrapper auf dieser Seite kann nicht geladen werden. Verwenden Sie die Schaltfläche "Zurück" im Browser, um es noch mal zu versuchen. Wenn das Problem weiterhin besteht, wenden Sie sich an den Administrator der Website.");
    }
  })(window);</script>
```

Quotation marks problem! This doesn't happen on eng sites!

- Verwenden Sie die Schaltfläche "Zurück" im Browser, um es noch mal zu
- "Technische Details"

How can i report this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging bugs/issues/"features" with the SharePoint Framework is currently done on the sp-dev-docs github page (link [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues)). Simply sign into github and click 'New Issue' to the upper right hand side of the page.

Please remember to follow the template provided.